# Get current class diagram target of t4 template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, t4

Currently, I have a T4 template (still empty), used for class diagram designers. So, let's say that I design a class (of any type), and I wanna get the the target class diagram which is using the T4 template. How do I do to get this? plus I wanna keep the generated code by the Diagram Class Designer. Is this possible??
Thanks by the way, any comment or answer.

**UPDATE:**

More important will be to process the usual diagram processor and then overwrite the generated code from my custom template. I've read about CodeModel but I still don't get it.

**UPDATE:**

Well, seems like nobody has an answer for me, so, all I need is to get de Class Diagram Designer Host or Service (I don't know), but there must be a way to do this.

Comment: Check out this post from my blog.  Perhaps it will be helpful:  http://www.keithholloway.net/blog/using-nets-system-reflection-to-aid-unit-test-creation-part-2/

Comment: I read the post I think it's what I want, but lack a little detail. I feel that you have not seen the upgrade post on time. The thing is that I want to keep the same code generated by the designer class diagram and then overwrite it with mine (written in my template). I read that CodeModel can help in this case. Thank you